# Using R cut function on dates

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe giving attendances at sports events

```
Crowd    matchDate
2345      1993-01-26
4567      1993-08-01
8888      1994-03-02
1298      1994-11-07
9876      1995-09-01 etc

1237      2011-09-09
```

The matchdate is a POSIXct class

I want to be able to create a season factor based on the date such that each season runs from, say, 1st August to 31 July e.g factor 1992/3 would include dates 1992-08-01 to 1993-07-31

ideally it would be a function that I could apply for several analyses, not necessarily with same start and end dates in the year

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.  `cut` does work on `POSIXct` objects (or, more precisely, there is a version of cut specialized for POSIXt objects).  It allows break and label specification.

Comment: Are you just breaking the year into quarters (Winter/Spring/Summmer/Fall)? Your example is 1992 - 1993 which is 1 month shy a year... as Brian mentioned, there is `?cut.POSIXct`, where you can set `breaks="quarter"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your question is more related to how you automatically generate the breaks and labels, maybe this will help

```
DF <- data.frame(matchDate = as.POSIXct(as.Date(sample(5000,100,replace=TRUE), origin="1993-01-01")))

years <- 1992:2011
DF$season <- cut(DF$matchDate, 
  breaks=as.POSIXct(paste(years,"-08-01",sep="")),
  labels=paste(years[-length(years)],years[-length(years)]+1,sep="/"))
```

Answer (score 16):

An example of my comment.

```
x <- as.Date(1:1000, origin = "2000-01-01")
x <- cut(x, breaks = "quarter")
```

And then relabel as you please, if necessary.

```
labs <- paste(substr(levels(x),1,4), "/", 1:4, sep="")
x <- factor(x, labels = labs)
```

---

```
?cut.POSIXct
```

> **breaks**
>   a vector of cut points or number giving the number of intervals which x is to be cut into or an interval specification, one
>   of "sec", "min", "hour", "day", "DSTday", "week", "month", "quarter"
>   or "year", optionally preceded by an integer and a space, or followed
>   by "s". (For "Date" objects only interval specifications using "day",
>   "week", "month", "quarter" and "year" are allowed.)