# Create a new column adding days based in two columns one have data and another ID

Tags: r, date, split, each, days

I have one data.frame `loc_teste2` with columns: `Ptt` (I have 36 differents Ptt's) and `Date`, like this:

```
Ptt      Date   
88734    05:39:18 23-Oct-2016  
88734    06:53:13 23-Oct-2016
88734    08:32:18 24-Oct-2016
88734    06:45:27 19-Dez-2016
88734    12:30:43 20-Dez-2016
129041   02:45:35 18-Nov-2016
129041   04:55:24 19-Nov-2016
129041   06:45:30 19-Nov-2016
129041   07:10:32 20-Nov-2016
129041   03:43:54 10-Jan-2017
120941   14:54:39 11-Jan-2017
...
```

So, I split the column `Date` in another column `Days`

```
loc_teste2$Date<- as.character(loc_teste2$Date)

loc_teste2$Days <- sapply(strsplit(loc_teste2$Date, split=' ', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))

loc_teste2$Days <- as.POSIXct(loc_teste2$Days, format = "%d-%b-%Y",tz = "GMT",usetz = TRUE)

loc_teste2$Date <- as.POSIXct(loc_teste2$Date, format = "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y",tz = "GMT",usetz = TRUE)
```

Returns:

```
Ptt      Date                       Days
88734    2016-10-23 05:39:18    2016-10-23
88734    2016-10-23 06:53:13    2016-10-23     
88734    2016-10-23 08:32:18    2016-10-24 
88734    2016-12-19 06:45:27    2016-12-19
88734    2016-12-20 12:30:43    2016-12-20
129041   2016-10-23 02:45:35    2016-10-18 
129041   2016-10-23 04:55:24    2016-11-19 
129041   2016-10-23 06:45:30    2016-11-19 
129041   2016-10-23 07:10:32    2016-11-20 
129041   2017-01-10 03:43:54    2017-01-10
120941   2017-01-11 14:54:39    2017-01-11
...
```

Then, I want to create a new column `Mig` adding 40 days based at the first date for each `Ptt` in column `Days`, where:
If the date is up to 40 days from the first date of the `Ptt`, returns `1`
If the date is after 40 days from the first date of the `Ptt`, it returns `2`, like this:

```
Ptt      Date                       Days        Mig
88734    2016-10-23 05:39:18    2016-10-23     1  #based in this date (the first date for this Ptt)
88734    2016-10-23 06:53:13    2016-10-23     1
88734    2016-10-23 08:32:18    2016-10-24     1 
88734    2016-12-19 06:45:27    2016-12-19     2
88734    2016-12-20 12:30:43    2016-12-20     2
129041   2016-10-23 02:45:35    2016-10-18     1  #based in this date (the first date for this Ptt)
129041   2016-10-23 04:55:24    2016-11-19     1 
129041   2016-10-23 06:45:30    2016-11-19     1 
129041   2016-10-23 07:10:32    2016-11-20     1 
129041   2017-01-10 03:43:54    2017-01-10     2
120941   2017-01-11 14:54:39    2017-01-11     2
...
```

Anybody have an idea how can do this?

Ps:It's better create an column `Mig` with the dates + 40 days, and then create another column `Mig2` with 1 or 2?

Comment: Maybe you could use `cut`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324934/using-r-cut-function-on-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the tidyverse and lubridate packages, you could take advantage of the group_by function and more easily manipulate dates. The code below has some intermediary steps to reproduce part of your data, but you may be able to just use the chunk after "group_by". It'll return a true or false instead of one or two, but you can edit the code with ifelse() function if you need that.

```
library(lubridate)
df <- read.delim(text = "Ptt      Date   
88734    05:39:18 23-Oct-2016  
88734    06:53:13 23-Oct-2016
88734    08:32:18 24-Oct-2016
88734    06:45:27 19-Dez-2016
88734    12:30:43 20-Dez-2016
129041   02:45:35 18-Nov-2016
129041   04:55:24 19-Nov-2016
129041   06:45:30 19-Nov-2016
129041   07:10:32 20-Nov-2016
129041   03:43:54 10-Jan-2017
120941   14:54:39 11-Jan-2017", sep = "\t")

df %>% 
  separate("Ptt......Date", into = c("ptt", "time", "date"), sep = "\\s+") %>% 
  mutate(date = str_replace(date, pattern = "Dez", replacement = "Dec"), date2 = dmy(date)) %>% 
  group_by(ptt) %>% 
  mutate(threshold = min(date2)+days(40), past_threshold = date2 > threshold)
```

Starting from the first dataframe with just Ptt and Date. Maybe try the following with lubridate and tidyverse loaded.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
loc_teste2 %>% 
  mutate(Ptt = as.character(Ptt), Date = as.character(Date), Date = str_replace(Date, pattern = "Dez", replacement = "Dec"), Date = parse_date_time(Date, order = "hmsdmy")) %>% 
  group_by(Ptt) %>% 
  mutate(Threshold = min(Date) + days(40)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Past_Threshold = Date > Threshold)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yfa, It worked a little! Returns the new columns `threshold` and `past_thereshold`, but the results is based only about one Ptt, not about each one Ptt, how can I fix that? I made this: `loc_teste2 %>% 
  group_by(Ptt) %>% 
  mutate(threshold = min(Days)+days(40), past_threshold = Days > threshold)`

Comment: Odd, using group_by should take the minimum `Days` for each Ptt to give you the threshold for that particular Ptt, then the code just compares each row to the threshold . Maybe check the structure `str(df)` of your dataframe compared to what copy and pasting my code give you. And check you don't have any `NA`. And check that your final dataframe with the new columns is a grouped df, `class(df)`. Otherwise, I'm not sure what the problem is, as my example code gives me the results you described.

Comment: I saw here, your df class is data.frame and the columns (after run your code) `Ptt` is character. My df is data.frame too, and the column `Ptt` it was int, but I changed to character, didn't work, then I changed to factor, didn't works too. I don't have any NA. And when I run the code my df class is `"grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`. I tried to changed to data.frame class, and run inside this, but didn't works too.

Comment: See my edit and if you get the same result as me. If not, I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: One last thing you may want to check would be namespace conlicts of the functions: https://peytonmccullough.com/post/resolving-name-conflicts-in-r/ Everything should be from dplyr, lubridate, or base r.

Comment: Very thank you! The problem was the package plyr, I detach this and it's works!